# Flutter firebase_ui_oauth plugin how to prevent headerBuilder from overflowing

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, oauth, firebaseui

Google's example has an image as a header for their example

```
SignInScreen(
```

I'm trying to put a custom animation instead. But it causes a renderflex overflow when I scroll.

I've tried setting `headerMaxExtent: 150`, the same height as the animation's Container widget, but the error persist.

`headerBuilder` takes various arguments I don't understand.

```
/// A builder that builds the contents of the header.
/// Used only on mobile platforms.
/// {@endtemplate}
typedef HeaderBuilder = Widget Function(
  BuildContext context,
  BoxConstraints constraints,
  double shrinkOffset,
);
```

I would like it to work without a renderflex error. But actually I would like the animation to work on web too. headerbuilder doesn't support web. If I put my animation outside Google's SignInScreen widget, then I image that would work, but I think I'd lose all the device responsiveness that the Google widget has, and would have to replicate it.

So what to do?!

I want to have a static animation header, that doesn't scroll over other widgets causing overflows and utilises Google's responsive layouts. And ideally also works on web.

```
            SignInScreen(
            actions: [
              ForgotPasswordAction((context, email) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  '/forgot-password',
                  arguments: {'email': email},
                );
              }),
              VerifyPhoneAction((context, _) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/phone');
              }),
              AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
                if (!state.user!.emailVerified) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/verify-email');
                } else {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
                }
              }),
              AuthStateChangeAction<UserCreated>((context, state) {
                if (!state.credential.user!.emailVerified) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/verify-email');
                } else {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
                }
              }),
              AuthStateChangeAction<CredentialLinked>((context, state) {
                if (!state.user.emailVerified) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/verify-email');
                } else {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
                }
              }),
              mfaAction,
              EmailLinkSignInAction((context) {
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/email-link-sign-in');
              }),
            ],
            styles: const {
              EmailFormStyle(signInButtonVariant: ButtonVariant.filled),
            },
            headerMaxExtent: 150,
            headerBuilder: (context, constraints, _) {
              return Column(children: [
                Container(height: 150, padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 0, 32, 4),child:
                FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    child:
                    ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 1, minHeight: 1),
                        child:
                        AnimatedTextKit(
                          animatedTexts: [
                            //FlickerAnimatedText('Flicker Frenzy'),
                            ScaleAnimatedText(
                              'Love thy neighbor as thyself',
                              textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2200),
                            ),
                          ],
                          pause: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                          totalRepeatCount: 1,
                          displayFullTextOnTap: true,
                          stopPauseOnTap: true,
                          repeatForever: false,
                        )
                    )
                )
                ),
              ]);
            },
```